# AJAX Closures and targeting 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the code example below the success callback function logs 'input#04.update' four times rather than each individual input, which makes sense seeing how closures work but how would I go about targeting each individual input using this.

```
<input type="text" name="" id="01" class="update">
<input type="text" name="" id="02" class="update">
<input type="text" name="" id="03" class="update">
<input type="text" name="" id="04" class="update">

function updateFields(){
 $('input.update').each(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      data: 'id=' + this.id,
      success: function(resp){
       console.log($this);
          $this.val(resp)
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You forgot `var`

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Don't forget `var`. One programmer who forgot `var` went to bed at night and woke up to find his apartment on fire. He added `var` and the fire went out.  Another programmer left `var` out *completely* shortly before leaving on a business trip to Europe. The airplane developed in-flight mechanical problems shortly after takeoff, causing the pilot to initiate emergency landing procedures. From his laptop the programmer quickly added `var` and the plane made it safely to an airport.

Don't forget `var`. If you put `var` in your code, you'll meet somebody special *today*. Try it. It sounds amazing but it really works!

Comment: That's amazing... but... could you tell me a technical reason to do that? I mean, I sometimes forget to add `var`... and I haven't had problems. But your words are scary, and from now on I won't forget to add `var`. Anyway... do you have a technical explanation for this kind of problems?

Comment: The reason: your `success` handler, anonymous function references a `$this` variable that is global. So every one of the 4 instances of this anonymous function references the same variable and therefore the same value, since they are executed long after the `each` function has returned.

Comment: @Cristian - Without the `var`, it's a global variable you're updating each loop, not local to this closure's scope which you want it do be in this case.

Comment: Nick's right - without an explicit `var`, not only will your love life fall apart completely, but your variables will all be global.

Comment: @Nick & @Pointy thank you so much... I'm glad to learn new things!

Comment: @Point - DOH! I'm so stupid at times. Well most of the time but that really was a beginner's mistake. Still, that was possibly the best response I've ever had to a question. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Pointy's correct on `var` usage, another alternative is to use [`$.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), like this:

```
function updateFields(){
 $('input.update').each(function(){
    $.ajax({
      data: 'id=' + this.id,
      success: $.proxy(function(resp){
                 $(this).val(resp);
               }, this)
    });
  });
}
```

This closure creator will make `this` refer to the input element when you're inside the `success` callback, which is usually what you're after...so I'm not sure why this isn't the case by default, but in any case [`$.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) rectifies the situation.

Comment: `$.proxy()` is nice but I wish it also supported the "parameter stuffing" or fake currying that Prototype's `.bind` supports. Now I'll have to check to see if the new ECMAScript 5 `.bind` is like Prototype's.

Comment: @Pointy - The second `$.proxy()` approach can do some mutation like this depending on how you structure it...but yeah it's not up to par prototype, but I think it's not really missing a lot...I think the 2 libraries just take a much different approach to binding and iteration with respect to closures, jQuery tends to create more for you along the way, for better or worse.

Comment: @Nick Craver - +1 - Thanks man. That's a great idea and one I wouldn't have considered.

Comment: @Pointy - what do you mean by 'parameter stuffing' or 'fake currying'?

Comment: Well it's a trick, like what `$.proxy` does for binding the "this" pointer. In addition, some libraries (like Prototype and Functional, and maybe Underscore) also let you take a function and generate a *new* function that will always supply some particular arguments to the original function. It's like, if you wanted something like the jQuery `attr()` function that *always* returned the "id", you could make a function that always called `attr('id')` and use it. It's a way of doing things that's common in the functional programming world (Scheme, Haskell, etc)